# How to access different members of class by using Traits pattern

Tags: c++, stl, vector, traits

I have a class that holds several vectors of objects:

```
struct ComponentA
{
 public:
   methodA1();
   float data1;
   ...
};
struct ComponentB
{
   ...
};
struct ComponentC
{
   ...
};
struct ComponentD
{
   ...
};

class Assembly
{
    vector<ComponentA> As;
    vector<ComponentB> Bs;
    vector<ComponentC> Cs;
    vector<ComponentD> Ds;
};
```

I would like to use traits and define a function that can return reference to members like this:

```
template< int T >
struct ComponentTraits;

template<>
ComponentTraits<TYPEA>
{
    typedef vector<ComponentA> data_type;
}
....
template< int T >
ComponentTraits<T>::data_type getComp(const Assembly & myassy)
{
    ...
}
```

such that a call

```
getComp<TYPEA>(thisassy)
```

would return a reference to As so I can manipulate at the vector level and access each component object method and data:

```
getComp<TYPEA>(thisassy).push_back(newcomponentA);
getComp<TYPEA>(thisassy).back().methodA1();
getComp<TYPEA>(thisassy).front().data1 = 5.0;
```

Thanks,

Wada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traits aren't going to do what you want here. C++ lacks the introspection support needed to say, "Get me the first member of class X that is of type Y." Also, traits are intended for "tell me more about type X" kinds of operations.

Template specialization can be used for this, but they'll be a lot of work:

```
template<class T>
T& getComp<T>(Assembly& assy);

template<>
ComponentA& getComp<ComponentA>(Assembly& assy)
{ return assy.As;
}

template<>
ComponentB& getComp<ComponentB>(Assembly& assy)
{ return assy.Bs;
}

template<>
ComponentC& getComp<ComponentC>(Assembly& assy)
{ return assy.Cs;
}

template<>
ComponentD& getComp<ComponentD>(Assembly& assy)
{ return assy.Ds;
}
```

Or shorter:

```
template<class T>
T& getComp<T>(Assembly& assy);

#define SpecializeGetComp(T, field) template<> \
T& getComp<T>(Assembly& assy) { return assy.field; }

SpecializeGetComp(ComponentA, As)
SpecializeGetComp(ComponentB, Bs)
SpecializeGetComp(ComponentC, Cs)
SpecializeGetComp(ComponentD, Ds)
```

You may also want to read up on Typelists (Chapter 3) in Alexandrescu's book *Modern C++ Design*. You might be able to use them in a Factory-like pattern, but that's way more than an SO answer really fits.

Comment: Mike, thanks for pointing out the lack of instrospection in C++.  I am reading up on Typelists now and hopefully learn a trick or two about templates.